# hg abort: cannot refresh immutable revision

Tags: version-control, mercurial, mercurial-queue

I'm using hg with the mq extension installed (I do not have the rebase extension to the best of my knowledge)

After making a few changes and doing a few qdiffs, qrefs I am suddenly faced with this error, I am not sure how or why it occured, but I'd like to be able to qref again and get rid of this error or atleast extract all my work from the given repo.

---

Outputs:

`hg qref`

```
abort: cannot refresh immutable revision
(see "hg help phases" for details)
```

-

`hg qseries`

```
0 A bug-822459-fix
```

-

`hg status`

```
M templates/testEmptyTest.js
M templates/testModalDialog.js
M templates/testPreferencesDialog.js
M templates/testSharedModules.js
```

and a whole lot of other untracked files ( files with a ? infront of them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hg phase -fd qbase:qtip` helps. See also https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Phases

I have this in my `~/.hgrc`:

```
[phases]
publish = False
```

Comment: I used hg phase --force --draft <my-changeset> to get it to work. Does -fd do the same thing?

Comment: @ffledgling: Yes, [according to the manual](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/phase) the `hg phase` switch `-f` is an alias to `--force` and `-d` to `--draft`

Answer (score 1):

The following command worked for me:

```
hg phase --force --draft .
hg qref
```